# How To Convert a List That Looks Like a DIct to a Real Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am unpacking a nested dictionary that I get from an API so I have no control over it. One of the sub dictionaries comes out as <class 'list'> in the form {'A':'B', 'C':'D', etc}. How can I convert this into a dictionary where the item on the left of the colon is the key and the item on the right is the value? I'm using python 3 if that helps.

```
def print_nested(dict_obj):
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs of a dict
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_nested(value)
        else:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                print(type(value))
                print(*value)
            else:
                print(key, ':', value)
```

produces output:

```
<class 'list'>
{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MSFT_031723C250', etc}
```

Comment: "<class 'list'> in the form {'A':'B', 'C':'D', etc}" - well, that can't be. Please provide real (simplified, if appropriate) data.

Comment: Please share python code, and the output, it'll be so easier to understand

Comment: You need to provide evidence of your controversial claims.

Comment: @Duncan can you please provide an example of that list? The example that you have provided doesn't look like a list.

Comment: As already suggested in the comments, please provide **real**, valid input data and the corresponding expected output. Your question just can't be answered as it is, as it is unclear, which is a valid reason for downvotes.

Comment: Also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67430360/edit) your question - code in the comments can't be formatted and is hard to read.

Comment: What you probably have is a dictionnary inside of a list , something like this: `value = [{'putCall': 'CALL', 'symbol': 'MSFT_031723C250', etc}]`

Comment: @python_ged good insight, I didn't think of that but you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from your code is consistent with there being a top-level dictionary that maps some unknown key to a list, which in its turn contains another dictionary.

You're being a bit mislead about the list contents because you're calling `print(*value)`, which is unpacking the list items into separate arguments to `print`. If you just did `print(value)` (without the `*`), you'd see the square brackets you'd expect from a list. It may be that your list contains only one item, but it's also possible that if it contains several large dictionaries the end of one and the start of the next may be hard to spot in the output.

I'm not sure what output you want if you had a structure like `{"foo": [{"bar": 1}]}`. Do you just want the inner most keys and values printed?

Then you probably want your list handling branch to be something like this (though you might need more logic if there might be lists that don't contain only dictionaries):

```
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for inner in value:
                print_nested(inner)
```

Answer (score -1):

i have a a way for concerting the list and set , to the dict:
you know that if you do the below activation , you would have error:

```
PSR=["hello","bye"]
PSR=dict(PSR)
print(PSR)
```

now , i want to show you a module to solve your problems:
we have module to name dict.fromkeys(list or set , value of keys), i made an example:

```
PSR=["hello","bye"]
#our primitive/first list
behave="good"
#the value of the keys 
PSR=dict.fromkeys(PSR,behave)
print(PSR)
#you will have a dict!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post does not answer the actual question and does not solve the issue in the question.

Comment: I had looked at this scheme, but the keys are fixed and you are just substituting in the values, i.e. "hello" and "bye" are both values. In my case "hello" is the key and "bye" is the value. @python_ged had it right in that it is actually a list of a dictionary.